# Save two monitor layouts and rotate among them with a shortcut

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I use multiple monitors, with a stand for multiple monitors that allows me to change their orientation easily.

Is there any way in Windows 11 to save the different layouts (one portrait, the other landscape, both landscape, etc.), such that I can rotate between these with some keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about native capabilities (I still use Win10), but I found that iRotate gives you shortcuts to rotate monitors quickly: https://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm

You may have to press key combinations a couple of times, but that will still be a fraction of the time required to go through those menus.

nVidia's Desktop Manager (assuming you use that brand of video card) used to have a shortcut function as well, however this seems to have disappeared from newer versions.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. It works like a charm.

Comment: There is a problem with iRotate that, since I have 3 monitors, it fixes Ctrl+Shift+arrows to rotate one of them, and so Ctrl+Shift+Left to select a word conflicts with that hotkey.